# Facebook TimeLine's cover system code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, facebook

I want to do a web page with the same system that Facebook TimeLine's cover . I want users to be able to upload a picture and reposition it.
I know how to upload picture with PHP but i don't know how to display it without reload the page. In my opinion I need to use AJAX. Is it right?
The last problem is : How does the reposition system works?(I know that Javascript is needed) If anybody can give me some help because I have no idea of what to search on google.
Thank you
PS: Sorry for my bad english .

Comment: yes, you'll need to use ajax. for repositioning, lots more javascript/css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps? 
[Ajax Image Upload without Refreshing Page using Jquery.](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html)